# checking for difference between two vector<T>

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11, vector

Suppose you have 2 vectors say `v1` and `v2` with the following values:

```
v1 = {8,4,9,9,1,3};
v2 = {9,4,3,8,1,9};
```

What is the most STL approach to check if they are "equal"? I am defining "equal" to mean the contents are the same regardless of the order. I would prefer to do this without sorting.

I was leaning towards building two `std::map<double, int>` to count up each of the vector's elements.

All, I need is a boolean Yes/No from the algorithm.

What say you?

Other conversations on Stack Overflow resort to sorting the vectors, I'd prefer to avoid that. Hence this new thread.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid sorting? Are you hoping there's an algorithm that's more efficient than sorting? Do you need to support types that aren't sortable?

Comment: if you really want to avoid sorting you could do something with a hash-based map. If you build an std::map you're sorting implicitly

Comment: What is the `double` going to be for in the `std::map<double, int>`?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use [`std::multiset<>](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset)?

Comment: Note that `std::map` *is* sorting.

Comment: @Johnsyweb: That would perform far worse than sorting.

Comment: @BillyONeal: Performance wasn't specified as a concern perhaps the only concern is code readability (it's not clear why the OP wants to avoid (explicitly) sorting).

Answer (score 4):

> I was leaning towards building two std::map to count up each of the vector's elements.

This will be far slower than just creating sorted vectors. (Note also that `std::map` *is* powered by sorting; it just does so using red-black trees or AVL trees) Maps are data structures optimized for an even mix of inserts and lookups; but your use case is a whole bunch of inserts followed by a whole bunch of lookups with no overlap.

I would just sort the vectors (or make copies and sort those, if you are not allowed to destroy the source copies) and then use vector's built in `operator ==`.

Comment: No - hashmaps are O(1) to insert, O(1) to look up.  This can be done in O(n) which is less than the O(n*log n) sort.

Comment: @djechlin: No, hash maps are *average case* O(1) to insert or look up if you have a good hash function for your starting data. Particularly if an attacker controls the data in question, that can very easily end up being closer to O(n). That really doesn't matter though; `std::map` is not a hash map, it is a binary tree.

Answer (score 4):

Sorting the vectors and call set_difference is still the best way. 
If the copy is heavy for you, the comparison between two unsorted arrays is even worse?

If you want current array untouched, you can make a copy of current arrays?

```
v1 = {8,4,9,9,1,3};
v2 = {9,4,3,8,1,9};

// can trade before copy/sort heavy work
if (v1.size() != v2.size()){
}     
std::vector<int> v3(v1);
std::vector<int> v4(v2);

sort(v3.begin(), v3.end());
sort(v4.begin(), v4.end());

return v3 == v4;
```

Comment: no need to reach for the iterators when you copy construct a vector. `std::vector<int> v3(v1), v4(v2);` should be just fine.

Comment: +1 for code example. You can just use `vector`'s copy constructor for v3 and v4 -- no need to use the range-based versions.

Comment: Why use `set_difference()` once you have the sorted arrays?  At that point just `return s3 == s4;`.

Comment: true, even faster, I've updated the code to your comment, thx

Answer (score 3):

I assume for some reason you can't sort the vectors, most likely because you still need them in their original order or they're expensive to copy. Otherwise, just sort them.

Create a "view" into each vector that allows you to see the vector in any order. You can do this with a vector of pointers that starts out pointing to the elements in order. Then sort the two views, producing a sorted view into each vector. Then compare the two views, comparing the two vectors in their view order. This avoids sorting the vectors themselves.

Comment: How is this better than just sorting the vectors themselves?

Comment: Presumably you still need the vectors for other things. And they could be cumbersome to copy. (He hasn't explained why he wants to avoid sorting, but this solves the most common reasons he might not want to.)

Comment: If anything I would just copy the vectors to avoid in-place modification, no need to think of a view.

Comment: What if the vectors contain objects that are 1MB each?

Comment: DV is me because 1) this still sorts and 2) additional complexity introduced with pointers.  I suppose in a more general situation than immutable data types (int's) or with particularly expensive copy operations this could make sense.  Removing DV for those benefits, recommend you explain that's the situation in which you would want to do this in your post.

Comment: @djechlin: Good idea. Done. (There's nothing wrong with using pointers that don't own what they point to as a "reseatable reference".)

Answer (score 1):

Was originally thinking of working in terms of sets since that's what you're actually thinking in terms of but that does necessitate sorting.  This can be done in `O(n)` by converting both to hashmaps and checking for equality there.

Answer (score -1):

just take the first vector and compare it with each element in the second vector.

If one value from the first one couldnt be find in the second the vectors are different. 
In the worst case it takes O(n*m) time which n = size of first vector and m = size second vector.

Comment: Why use the `n^2` algorithm when a `2 n lg n + n` algorithm is just as easy?

Answer (score -1):

This util method will help you to compare 2 int[], let me know in case of any issues

public static boolean compareArray(int[] v1, int[] v2){

```
    boolean returnValue = false;

    if(v1.length != v2.length)
        returnValue = false;

    if(v1.length == 0 || v2.length == 0)
        returnValue = false;

    List<Integer> intList =  Ints.asList(v2);

    for(int element : v1){
        if(!intList.contains(element)){
            returnValue = false;
            break;
        }else{
            returnValue = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: -1: Not C++. C++ has no `List`, `Integer`, `Ints`, or `contains`.